# Integral $\int_0^1\log(1+x)\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^4}dx=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{23}{72}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

EDIT:  Small Typo Fixed now, Thanks to Sir Chen Wang!

Hi I am trying to prove this result without using a series approach 
$$
\int_0^1\log(1+x)\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^4}dx=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{23}{72}.
$$I know we can just solve it by writing
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left( \int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(1+x)^4}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2+n}}{(1+x)^4}dx\right),
$$
which leads to summing a bunch of Harmonic numbers which is not so easy.
This method is brute force but I often have trouble summing harmonic numbers, can we prove it another way?

Thanks

Comment: I messed around with it using differentiation under the integral.  Looks like you can do it but end up with some really nasty stuff.  The way you mentioned in the post may be the best way!

Comment: @TylerHG THank you for the comment.  Yes I guess it may be a feasible way of doing it, however it involves the special functions so I thought maybe somebody would be clever enough to avoid these :)

Comment: $\int_0^1\log(1+x)\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^4)^2}dx\approx0.3499, -\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{23}{72}\approx 0.0884$. I suggest OP check for possible typos.

Comment: @ChenWang Thank you Sir for your insight and noticing the error.  I just woke up this morning and have fixed the Typo.  Thank you very much for your help as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
I&=\int^1_0\log(1+x)\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^4}dx\\
&=-\frac13\int^1_0\log(1+x)d\left(\frac{2+3x+3x^2}{(1+x)^3}\right)\\
&=-\frac13\left(\left.\log(1+x)\frac{2+3x+3x^2}{(1+x)^3}\right|^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{2+3x+3x^2}{(1+x)^3}d\,\log(1+x)\right)\\
&=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac13\int^1_0\frac{2+3x+3x^2}{(1+x)^4}dx\\
&=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac13\int^1_0\left(\frac{2}{(1+x)^4}-\frac{3}{(1+x)^3}+\frac{3}{(1+x)^2}\right)dx\\
&=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac13\left(\frac{7}{12}-\frac{9}{8}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\log 2}{3}+\frac{23}{72}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You often use this method of writing part of the integrand as a derivative, it is very clever.  In this case it completely removes integrating the log.  Thanks for this insight on solving integrals +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write $\ln(a+x)$ and then differentiate with regards to *a*. Your integrand becomes a rational function. **Observation:** Please note that by multiplying the end result by $3$, we have $\dfrac{69}{72}-\ln2$. Since the integrand is obviously positive, this leads me to believe that this integral was originally meant as an exercise, much similar to [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_pi), in showing that $\ln2<\dfrac{23}{24}$ . The choice of numbers is especially interesting since, on one hand, $\ln2\approx69\%$, and on the other hand, the famous [rule of $72$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72), still used in economics until today, is also connected to the same transcendental quantity, $\ln2$.

Comment: Nice observation!

Comment: What makes you think the idea was to show $\log 2 < \frac{23}{24}$, can you explain again?  Thank you +1 , but I am not sure I can follow your insight yet since I do not quite understand the depth of it!   I am still looking for a full solution so I will not check as the answer though.  +1

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}{1+x^{2} \over \pars{1 + x}^{4}}\,\dd x
     =-\,{\ln\pars{2} \over 3} + {23 \over 72}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}{1+x^{2} \over \pars{1 + x}^{4}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{1}^{2}\ln\pars{x}{x^{2} - 2x + 2 \over x^{4}}\,\dd x
> =\fermi\pars{-2} -2 \fermi\pars{-3} + 2\fermi\pars{-4}
> \end{align}

where
\begin{align}
\fermi\pars{n}&\equiv\int_{1}^{2}\ln\pars{x}x^{n}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to n}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{1}^{2}x^{\mu}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to n}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{2^{\mu + 1} - 1 \over \mu + 1}
\\[3mm]&={2^{n + 1}\ln\pars{2} \over n + 1}
+ {1 - 2^{n + 1} \over \pars{n + 1}^{2}}
\end{align}

> Then
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}{1+x^{2} \over \pars{1 + x}^{4}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\bracks{%
> {2^{-2 + 1}\ln\pars{2} \over -2 + 1} + {1 - 2^{-2 + 1} \over \pars{-2 + 1}^{2}}}
> -2\bracks{%
> {2^{-3 + 1}\ln\pars{2} \over -3 + 1} + {1 - 2^{-3 + 1} \over \pars{-3 + 1}^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&\!\!\!+2\bracks{%
> {2^{-4 + 1}\ln\pars{2} \over -4 + 1} + {1 - 2^{-4 + 1} \over \pars{-4 + 1}^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\bracks{-\,\half\,\ln\pars{2} + \half}
> +\bracks{{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2} - {3 \over 8}}
> +\bracks{-\,{1 \over 12}\,\ln\pars{2} + {7 \over 36}}
> \\[3mm]&=\underbrace{\pars{-\,\half + {1 \over 4} - {1 \over 12}}}
> _{\ds{=\ -\,{1 \over 3}}}\ln\pars{2}\ +\
> \underbrace{\pars{\half - {3 \over 8} + {7 \over 36}}}_{\ds{=\ {23 \over 72}}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}{1+x^{2} \over \pars{1 + x}^{4}}\,\dd x
=-\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln\pars{2} + {23 \over 72}} \approx 0.0884
$$

Comment: Dear Felix, I really like your answer, but I can't see how you've derived this step: $$\int_{1}^{2}\ln\pars{x}x^{n}\,\dd x
=\lim_{x \to n}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{1}^{2}x^{\mu}\,\dd x$$
Could you please clarify?
Also, is the variable in the limit correct? Shouldn't it be $\mu \rightarrow n$? Regards.

Comment: @Pringoooals Yes. It was a typo. Fixed. The correct one is, as you said, $\lim_{\mu \to n}$. It uses the identity
${\large{{\rm d}a^{z} \over {\rm d}z} = a^{z}\ln\left(a\right)}$. Thanks.